# HTML text input event

Tags: html, input, events, keypress, textinput

I have a form, and want to disable/enable its submit button depending on whether the form's input text fields are empty or have had text entered into them.

I think this means having an event handler for the input text fields' `keydown` or `keypress` events: when it's fired, this event handler should test whether the input text fields contain text, and enable or disable the submit button accordingly.

The `change` event looks like it ought to be more useful than the `keydown` or `keypress` events, except that it isn't fired until the control in question loses the focus, and what good is that: since the user wants to just type something and then click on the submit button, I want an event handler that's fired by text being entered and not only when the control loses focus.

My questions are:

- Are `keydown` and/or `keypress` events fired before or after the corresponding text has been inserted into the input text field?
- Are `keydown` and/or `keypress` events cancellable (can you cancel them to prevent the corresponding text from being entered)?

---

**Edit:** FYI, the [jQuery validation plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722315/jquery-validation-rules/1722325#1722325) re-tests form validity on key up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your questions...

1. The keydown or keypress events can
   be intercepted before text is input
   using javascript
2. You can return false after binding a
   function to the keydown or keypress
   event.  This will prevent the text
   from being input.

**Example using jQuery:**

```
$("#inputfield").live("keydown", function(){
    return false;
});
```

If you want to test some input for value on form submit you can do that using jQuery [submit()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit).

```
$("#theform").submit(function() {
    var formval = $("#theinput").val();
    if(formval == "") { //or some better test
        alert("input value"); //or some other alert...
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Returning false will invalidate the click to submit the form.

**Edit:**
If as you say in your comments you want to disable the submission of the form until requirements are met for the input field(s)

```
$("#inputfield").live("keyup", function(){
    if($("#inputfield").val() == "") {
        $('#button').attr("disabled", true); 
    } else {
        $('#button').attr("disabled", false); 
    }
});
```

You want to use the "[keyup](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keyup)" event handler to allow the text to be sent first. see my example: [on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/epavo/)

Comment: If they're fired before the text is entered, doesn't that make them useless for the purpose for which I intended to use them (which was to test whether the input fields contain text)? What other mechanism can I use instead (to enable/disable the submit button depending on whether input fields contain text)?

Comment: You can put a test in place onsubmit to check if there is something in the input field.

Comment: Doing that would be a little later than I wanted: it's common, in a desktop application at least, to enable/disable a dialog's "OK" button in realtime depending on whether it's valid/clickable. You're saying, instead, to let the button be clickable all the time (so that onsubmit can always be invoked), but to check in onsubmit (and I suppose display an error message to say that a field is required). I realize that's a common/usual way to do it in a browser; I was wondering whether the technology (i.e. behaviour of available events) even supported the other UI.

Comment: Sure you can disable it until text is entered. (that will give a visual clue that something is missing.) Just test the input value on every keydown and toggle the disabled attribute: $('#target').attr("disabled", true); whenever your requirements for the field are met.

Comment: But you said that keydown is fired before the text is entered: so testing in keydown would be too early to know whether the input field contains text.

Comment: Instead of testing on key down, test onblur. This will get fired when the field loses focus whether the user typed something in or just left it blank

Comment: Test onkeyup. Or onblur as suggested above.

Comment: Again, onblur and/or onchange don't seem to be exactly what I want. I'd like to be able to 1) Position the input focus on an input text field; 2) Press a key, for example 'a'; 3) Therefore see the "OK" button being enabled (without having needed to do something that causes the input text field to lose focus).

Comment: Ok I think my example using on keyup fulfills those requirements.

Comment: Is it possible to initiate an asynchronous check? If I were faced with this situation in Windows, I'd use the PostMessage or  BeginInvoke APIs. For example, when the keydown handler fires, is there an API to initiate an asynchronous event/method callback, which will be invoked after this event (and its default processing, i.e. updating the input control) has been allowed to complete: for example, is there any way to say "call this other method after some tiny asynchronous delay"?