# Jquery - validation - Rules

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I use JQ - validation plugin to validate my form. But i dont know what kind of validation rules in jquery! Could you suggest me a page where i can read about rules?

I have two field, NAME and AGE, and i want it to validate for REQUIRED, MAXLENGTH, NUMBER /CHAR, MIN, MAX

```
 rules: {
    new_name: {
    required: true,
    maxlength: 30,
    **number: false  //?? I dont want to allowd numbers, only alphabetic chars.**

 },
 new_age: {
    required: true,
    maxlength: 3,
    **chars: false  //?? I dont want to allowd numbers, only alphabetic chars.**
    **min: 1 // 1 is the lowest number what they allowed**
     **max: 30 // 120 is the highest number what they allowed**
 },
```

Is it possible, without write an own rule?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find everything about the validation plugin here: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Furthermore, reading the code of the examples might help you: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Comment: Thank you. I find everything except the " Chars " - not number rule. What do you think, how can i validate to only accept " a-z" chars?

Comment: Lettersonly - this is the key:)

Answer (score 0):

You can find your validating requirements for `chars` using regex here:
[JQuery validate: How to add a rule for regular expression validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation)